# Access Session Values in a AddHttpMessageHandler Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to create a generic way to add my access token to my outgoing calls in a Razor application.  I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#outgoing-request-middleware) to add an `DelegatingHandler` via `AddHttpMessageHandler`:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyName").AddHttpMessageHandler<AddAuthorizationHeaderHandler>();
```

My handler is called correctly, but I can't find a way to get at the session value that holds the access token (so I can add it as a header).

ASP.Net Core is storing this value in the cookie.  In the "code behind" of my page, I can get at the value via `HttpContext` (a public member of the `PageModel` class).  Like this:

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

The problem I have is that I can't find a way to get access to this `HttpContext` in my `DelegatingHandler`.

**How can I get at the session value of `access_token` in my `DelegatingHandler`?**

Comment: Show the handler. Why not just inject `IHtpContextAccessor` into the delegating handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `IHtpContextAccessor` into the delegating handler

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

public AddAuthorizationHeaderHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
    this.accessor = accessor
}
```

So that you can have access to the context

*AddAuthorizationHeaderHandler.SendAsync*

```
//...

var accessToken = await accessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

//...
```

Make sure to register it with the service collection

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  I did not know that it would do dependency injection on the class.  Thank you!